# How avoid drop database on code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am working with a tutorial demo, and the second time I run it got and error:

> Cannot drop database 'CustomerManager' because it is currently in use.

[image]

I found a section looks like is causing the problem.

```
namespace CustomerManager.Repository
{
    ////DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TodosContext>
    public class CustomerManagerDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<CustomerManagerContext> // re-creates every time the server starts
    {
        protected override void Seed(CustomerManagerContext context)
        {
            DataInitializer.Initialize(context);
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
// DEVELOPMENT ONLY: initialize the database
static CustomerManagerContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CustomerManagerDatabaseInitializer());
}
```

What I have to add/remove so only create the db if doesn't exists?

My guess is change the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` for something else.

Comment: Use `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` instead of `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` More info on database initialization strategies: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Those initializers are really only good for very early development when your model is constantly changing. When you get to the point where you need to keep unseeded data consider using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`.

Comment: @12seconds Thanks After asking the question I went and look at the  namespace `System.Data.Entity` documentation for a `DropCreateDatabaseNever`  and  found the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists `